# How to get QTextBrowser to always insert text at the end

Tags: c++, qt, qtextbrowser, qtextcursor

I am trying to make a serial terminal program by using `QTextBrowser` to display incoming data from a serial port. I have set a `QTimer` to call the paintEvent every 100ms, and show characters on the `QTextBrowser` widget if anything was received on the serial port.

My problem is that every time I click say in the middle of the `QTextBrowser`, it is as if though the cursor moves and then on all subsequent `ui->tbOutput->insertPlainText(QString(buf));`, only half of the `QTextBrowser` gets updated.

When I click on the bottom of the `QTextBrowser` widget, the whole `QTextBrowser` is updated again.

This is the code that I have, where from various other articles, I have tried to scroll to the bottom, and move the text cursor to the end, but it does not do what I want.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    static char buf[10240];

    if (terminal->serialport.bytesAvailable() > 0)
    {
        // sizeof(buf)-1 so that there is space for zero termination character
        qint64 numread = terminal->serialport.read(buf,sizeof(buf)-1); 

        if ((numread > 0) && (numread < sizeof(buf)))
        {
            buf[numread] = 0; // set zero termination
            ui->tbOutput->insertPlainText(QString(buf));
            ui->tbOutput->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(
                ui->tbOutput->verticalScrollBar()->maximum());

            ui->tbOutput->textCursor().setPosition(QTextCursor::End);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

- [`QTextBrowser::textCursor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textCursor) returns a copy, so any modification is not applied to the document
- [`QTextBrowser::setPosition`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#setPosition) moves the cursor to an absolute position, therefore you are always moving to position 11 (int value to `QTextCursor::End`). Use [`QTextBrowser::movePosition`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#movePosition) instead
- finally, it would be better to move the cursor *before* adding the text, so you are sure it will be added at the end of the document.

Here the modified code:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    static char buf[10240];

    if (terminal->serialport.bytesAvailable() > 0)
    {
        // sizeof(buf)-1 so that there is space for zero termination character
        qint64 numread = terminal->serialport.read(buf,sizeof(buf)-1); 

        if ((numread > 0) && (numread < sizeof(buf)))
        {
            buf[numread] = 0; // set zero termination
            auto textCursor = ui->tbOutput->textCursor();
            textCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
            ui->tbOutput->setTextCursor(textCursor);
            ui->tbOutput->insertPlainText(QString(buf));
            ui->tbOutput->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(
                ui->tbOutput->verticalScrollBar()->maximum());
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, some additional considerations:

- [`QIODevice::read(char* data, qint64 maxSize)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#read) will read at most `maxSize` bytes, so checking if the number of read bytes is smaller than your buffer is unnecessary.
- Do not do it in the `paintEvent`, it is not the place to read data but to display it. Instead, connect the timer with a slot and read data there and re-paint your console (`ui->tbOutput->update()`) only if new data has arrived.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer got me on to the right track. I agree with your additional considerations and have implemented them in my code.